# Looping bootstrap panels

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

The existing code is something like this (well-xxxx are custom wells which applies the brand colors to default wells)->

```
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">
  <div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2015" href="#year2015" title="Click to expand/collapse">
        <h4 class="panel-title">Publication Year: 2015 (4 publications until now)</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="year2015" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="well well-info"><p>Title/Brief</p><p>Author</p></div>
            <div class="well well-info"><p>Title/Brief</p><p>Author</p></div>
            <div class="well well-info"><p>Title/Brief</p><p>Author</p></div>
            <div class="well well-info"><p>Title/Brief</p><p>Author</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-warning">
    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2014" href="#year2014" title="Click to expand/collapse">
        <h4 class="panel-title">Publication Year: 2014</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="year2014" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="well well-warning"><p>Title/Brief</p><p>Author</p></div>
            <div class="well well-warning"><p>Title/Brief</p><p>Author</p></div>
            <div class="well well-warning"><p>Title/Brief</p><p>Author</p></div>
            <div class="well well-warning"><p>Title/Brief</p><p>Author</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-success">
    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2013" href="#year2013" title="Click to expand/collapse">
        <h4 class="panel-title">Publication Year: 2013</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="year2013" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="well well-success"><p>Title/Brief</p><p>Author</p></div>
            <div class="well well-success"><p>Title/Brief</p><p>Author</p></div>
            <div class="well well-success"><p>Title/Brief</p><p>Author</p></div>
            <div class="well well-success"><p>Title/Brief</p><p>Author</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

there would be an array that will store the bootstrap brands ('info','warning','primary','success').. & the repeating contents will have the brand classes in a loop. like if one panel is one panel is primary.. next is success.. then again info.. both php n jquery solutions are welcome.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: see my code.. there is a repeating pattern.. I want to make a loop for printing the panels

Comment: I reviewed your code, neither it nor your additional comment sufficiently states your question for us to be able to help you. Where is your data coming from? Are these some sort of accordion layout? Will each panel have different information? Is that information available on load or loaded via ajax? There are dozens of questions like this we could end up asking. We can help, but first, you will need to clearly sate what you are trying to accomplish, what you have tried, and how what you tried has failed to accomplish your goal.

Comment: feel free to downvote.. but please share your opinion on why did you did it

Comment: I was one on the downvotes, for the reasons stated above. It's not personal, but as it stands the question has very little value on SO. Votes can be changed though. Explain better what it is you are having your problem with and Im sure the count will reverse :)

Comment: @DelightedD0D the parent panels will have publications from a certain year. the children accordians will display the publication lists.. each panel will display different data.. but that's my headache.. i just want a simple loop which will add the brands to the classnames & add the year to everywhere the accordian id is mentioned

Comment: Where does this data come from, you'd be much better served by building the sections in a more logical way, but its hard to say what that would look like with out seeing your datastore. Are you working with JSON data by chance?

Comment: like 2015 panel contains an accordian which will show the 2015 publications if expanded

Comment: no i am using active records (codeigniter).. i will pass the values through my controller

Comment: Yeah, see that's a huge detail, you should add a code igniter tag to your question. Sorry I've never used it so not realy much help there

Comment: i didn't add that detail coz i dont need help on populating them.. the question is actually simple.. i can work it out if i think.. i just didn't want to think much.. anyways thanks

Comment: You seem to be generating all of these elements then trying to go back and modify the elements to make them do what you want. What you should do instead is figure out how to generate the elements with the desired properties set from the beginning. I'm not sure what that would look like using codeigniter but I'd bet there are some methods built in that will do this for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i understood that you want to `loop` on `twitter-bootstrap` classes

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion1">
<?php $brands = array('info','warning','primary','success');
$year = '2015';
//loop brands
foreach($brands as $brand): 
?>
  <div class="panel panel-<?php echo $brand; ?>">
    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion<?php echo $year; ?>" href="#year<?php echo $year; ?>" title="Click to expand/collapse">
        <h4 class="panel-title">Publication Year: <?php echo $year; ?> (4 publications until now)</h4>
    </div>
    <div id="year<?php echo $year; ?>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="well well-<?php echo $brand; ?>"><p>Title/Brief</p><p>Author</p></div>
            <div class="well well-<?php echo $brand; ?>"><p>Title/Brief</p><p>Author</p></div>
            <div class="well well-<?php echo $brand; ?>"><p>Title/Brief</p><p>Author</p></div>
            <div class="well well-<?php echo $brand; ?>"><p>Title/Brief</p><p>Author</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php 
$year--;
endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks.. foreach is simplest

Comment: this really helped to me.

Answer (score 0):

This will print panels from 2015 to $year_limit which you can set to whatever is you need

```
<?php $year = 2015;
      $year_limit = 1990;
      $i =0;
      $brand = array('info', 'warning', 'success');
while($year < $year_limit){
    if($i == 3)
       $i =0;?>
    <div class="panel panel-<?php echo $brand[$i];?>">
    <div class="panel-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion<?php echo $year;?>" href="#year<?php echo $year;?>" title="Click to expand/collapse">
        <h4 class="panel-title">Publication Year: <?php echo $year;?></h4>
    </div>
    <div id="year<?php echo $year;?>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="well well-<?php echo $brand[$i];?>"><p>Title/Brief</p><p>Author</p></div>
            <div class="well well-<?php echo $brand[$i];?>"><p>Title/Brief</p><p>Author</p></div>
            <div class="well well-<?php echo $brand[$i];?>"><p>Title/Brief</p><p>Author</p></div>
            <div class="well well-<?php echo $brand[$i];?>"><p>Title/Brief</p><p>Author</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php $year--; $i++;?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: sorry karan's solution is better.

Comment: you still need the wells set